# Javascript change url parameter before putting it in history

Tags: javascript, browser-history, http-request-parameters

I'm using the datatables JQuery plugin. I use it with AJAX and pagination (server-side). Each row contains a link to a detailed view of that record. When clicking in that link and then on the back button I want to return to the previous page. (Note: datatables own state-saving can't be used).

This could be achieved If you could add a url parameter to the current url before it is put into the history.

Can this be done? pure JS or JQuery does not really matter.

(Note: I'm quite new do this kind of stuff, have read about using the # for this but never done it so if you recommend that please provide an example applicable to my problem)

EDIT:

Very basic Guide for JQuery plugin bbq 
(http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)

Assuming URL has a hash of #a=2&b=test, you can get the values by:

```
//true = optional converts 2 to an integer, false to boolean,...
var a = $.bbq.getState('a',true);
```

You can change/add a value by:

```
var hash = "a=3&b=hello";
$.bbq.pushState(hash);
```

pushState fires hashchange Event in case it is bound. To bind the event but following in doucment.ready function:

```
// called when # part of URL is modified
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function( event ) {
    var hash = event.fragment; // full hash as string
    var a = event.getState('a', true ); // value for a
    // here do meaningful action like an AJAX request using the hash parameters    
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the [HTML5 History API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html) allows you to do just that. Check out the [Manipulating the Browser History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) article at MDN.

Here is an example that adds a parameter to the current URL and replaces the current history entry:

```
 var newURL = location.href + (location.search ? "&" : "?") + "myParameter=myValue";
 history.replaceState({}, '', newURL);
```

The History API is an HTML5 feature and unfortunately [not supported on all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=history). However, there is a polyfill named [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js), which claims to bring support to all browsers.

UPDATE:

Instead of rolling your own AJAX history implementation you would probably want to look at existing solutions and jQuery plugins. Have a look e.g. at the answers to the [What is the best back button jQuery plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin) question.

Comment: thx. I've vaguely heard about HTML5 history API but sadly the application must run in IE 8 and according to your link IE 8 is not supported. I went with http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ referred in you link (plus found googling